# MySQL Laravel making foreign key unique

Tags: mysql, laravel, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

In my app built using Laravel/Mysql I have two tables for users.

When I user register the table "**User**" and "**UserInfo**" gets created.

**UserInfo** has a *FK* that points to the *PK* in the **Users** table.

Right now I have a column in my **UserInfo** table that is set to *unique* I do this to make sure that user only can have one record in the UserInfo table.

But is it possible to just make the FK unique? I need a one-to-one design between the tables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just make the integer itself unique. The foreign method is only used to link those datas between table A and table B.

```
$table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->unique();
$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('user_infos');
```

What you are probably looking for is Eloquent:Relationships and must be added to your Models.

You can add this for your UserInfo Model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(UserInfo::class);
}
```

And this for your User Model:

```
    public function user_info()
{
    return $this->hasOne(User::class);
}
```

Further information:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships

Answer (score 0):

For Laravel 9, if you're using the `foreignId` conventional function , you can just simply do

```
$table->foreignId('user_id')->unique()->constrained();
```

in your migration.